# querySelectorAll polyfill for all DOM nodes

Tags: javascript

So because of a bunch of odd circumstances I have to make sure a particular widget I worked on awhile back has to work on Firefox 3.0.1. I got most of it working, but my current issue is that a library I'm dependent on for parts of the widget need querySelectorAll/querySelector available on any DOM element

The current polyfill I'm using appends it to document:

```
if (!document.querySelectorAll) {
document.querySelectorAll = function(selector) {
    var doc = document,
        head = doc.documentElement.firstChild,
        styleTag = doc.createElement('STYLE');
    head.appendChild(styleTag);
    doc.__qsaels = [];

    styleTag.sheet.insertRule(selector + "{x:expression(document.__qsaels.push(this))}", 0);
    window.scrollBy(0, 0);

    return doc.__qsaels;
}
```

}

Is there a polyfill I've missed that allows a similar function to be accessible from any selected node? So for instance, if I were to take one of the elements returned by this function I could call this function on it again to find another node child to the first?

Thanks : )

Comment: https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/polyfill.js#L652

Comment: If you have to support such old browsers I would just use jQuery and forget about polyfilling the DOM yourself.

Comment: Also this is the selectors polyfill recommended by modernizr https://github.com/termi/CSS_selector_engine

Comment: You can try modifying `Element.prototype`, e.g., `Element.prototype.foo = function(){alert('fooing')}`. But I'm not sure if FF3 will like this or not...

Comment: Ended up using https://github.com/termi/CSS_selector_engine per megawacs suggestion. 

The reason I'm not using jQuery is because the library that's failing isn't written in such a way where I can shim it in.

Comment: ff3 does indeed allow dom protos to be defined on Element.prototype, but the method shown only polyfills IE using quirky M$ syntax.

Comment: Element.prototype.querySelectorAll=Element.prototype.querySelectorAll||function(sel){return query(this, sel);}; where query is a css engine...

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered the https://polyfill.io service, which can give you a querySelector polyfill by simply adding a script to your document:

```
<script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=document.querySelector"></script>
```